# bg color on row divs

Tags: css

I'm trying to learn how to put table content into css floats.

My approach has been to use a div at the "table" level, at the "row" level, and the "cell" level. Not sure this is a good strategy.

Anyway, when I set a background style at the "table" or "cell" level I can see the color change. When I set it at the row level it stays white.

Any guesses what's going on? Is there a better way to do this?

```
<h2>"Tables" work</h2>
<div style="width: 455px; background-color:#a4c4fc">
    <div>
        <div style="width: 70px; float: left">ID</div>
        <div style="width: 220px; float: left">Lemons</div>
        <div style="width: 50px; float: left">Horseradish</div>
    </div>
    <br clear: both>
    <div>
        <div style="width: 70px; float: left">1<LEFT></div>
        <div style="width: 220px; float: left">3</div>
        <div style="width: 50px; float: left">4</div>
    </div>
</div>

<br>

<h2>"Row" divs do not seem to work</h2>
<div style="width: 455px">
    <div style="background-color:#a4c4fc">
        <div style="width: 70px; float: left">ID</div>
        <div style="width: 220px; float: left">Lemons</div>
        <div style="width: 50px; float: left">Horseradish</div>
    </div>
    <br clear: both>
    <div style="background-color:#a4c4fc">
        <div style="width: 70px; float: left">0</div>
        <div style="width: 220px; float: left">0</div>
        <div style="width: 50px; float: left">1</div>
    </div>
</div>

<br>

<h2>Individual cell divs work</h2>
<div style="width: 455px">
    <div style="background-color:#a4c4fc">
        <div style="width: 70px; float: left; background-color:#a4c4fc">ID</div>
        <div style="width: 220px; float: left; background-color:#a4c4fc">Lemons</div>
        <div style="width: 50px; float: left; background-color:#a4c4fc">Horseradish</div>
    </div>
    <br clear: both>
    <div style="background-color:#a4c4fc">
        <div style="width: 70px; float: left; background-color:#a4c4fc">0</div>
        <div style="width: 220px; float: left; background-color:#a4c4fc">0</div>
        <div style="width: 50px; float: left; background-color:#a4c4fc">1</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? Tables are perfectly acceptable for tabular content...

Comment: What I mean to say is, I really hope this is not a misguided extension of the completely legitimate crusade against table-based layouts. Tables are valid and semantic HTML when they are used for their intended purpose.

Comment: @David: The numerical values are placeholders for things like edit/delete buttons, etc. The lemons and horseradish are also, um, for show. Interesting about the factions/crusades, legitimacey.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like tabular data.

If it is, you should use a HTML `table` element to display this information.

Too many people make the mistake of hearing "tables are bad", and try and do work arounds using div's, even when tables are most appropriate.

When people say you shouldn't use tables, they are referring to layout structure. It is still fine to use it in this case, they are not evil!

Then you'll be able to do:

```
<tr style="background-color:#a4c4fc;">

</tr>
```

---

If you are certain on using div's your issue is because the "cell" divs are all `float:left;`. Therefore your "row" div doesn't have a height.

You could add the following to the bottom of the "cell"'s to fix this:

```
<div style="background-color:#a4c4fc">
        <div style="width: 70px; float: left">ID</div>
        <div style="width: 220px; float: left">Lemons</div>
        <div style="width: 50px; float: left">Horseradish</div>
        <div style="clear:both;overflow:hidden;height:0;"></div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, use `display:inline-block;`

```
<div style="background-color:#a4c4fc">
        <div style="width: 70px; display:inline-block;">ID</div>
        <div style="width: 220px; display:inline-block;">Lemons</div>
        <div style="width: 50px; display:inline-block;">Horseradish</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hRCWk/2/

But don't do that, use a `table` :)

Comment: Good answer. But why the need to float divs at all. Pretty sure you could use `display:inline-block` to better effect. Still, a table is the best option here

Comment: Just made a quick fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/hRCWk/2/, and you're right! Never knew that before. But yeah, either way, `table` is the solution

Answer (score 2):

Clear your floats. Add `overflow:hidden;` to your row div.

Also, `<br clear: both>` makes no sense. Remove it or use `<div style="clear:both;"></div>`

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/RX8Pq/

Answer (score 1):

The row element isn't stretching because all the sub elements are floated:

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html

Answer (score 1):

Instead of floating you DIV elements you could set them to display as inline blocks...

```
display:inline-block;
```

then you dont need to clear the DIV floats afterwards.

Of course, you should just use a table anyway

**NOTE**: Apparently this will not work in IE8 and earlier versions.

Comment: `inline-block` will not work with naturally block elements in <IE8

Comment: @AlienWebguy: Lots of things don't work in IE8, but I don't see a spec that says this had to

Comment: it's probably for the best to not give a solution which does not work for half the user base. I work at Dictionary.com and over 70% of our users are on IE8. It's an unfortunate reality, not a spec.

Comment: @AlienWebguy: Guess I missed the bit where this was for the users of Dictionary.com... who knows, maybe the OP user base is just his work office where everyone is forced to use Chrome... it fair enough for you to point out the compatibility issues in my answer, but it is a valid solution in many situations

Comment: Replace Dictionary.com with any high-traffic website. The point is that it's probably a better idea to avoid offering solutions which will get the OP into trouble later on, or not even pass QA for that matter. This solution is a time-waster and while I wholeheartedly agree that the world would be a better place if everybody used Chrome, everybody doesn't - you should at least mention the limitations of your solution in your answer.